# set default arguments for cmd.exe commands

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Is there an option in command prompt (cmd.exe) that comes with windows to set default command arguments. For example, I may want `dir /a` every time I run `dir` to show hidden files.  For sake of convenience I would like to set `/a` to be always enabled even if I don't provide the option.

To get a list of all commands I'm talking about type `help` at the prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create cmd aliases. doskey seems to work just fine. Allows you to configure a set of parameters against a text file. This link might be of help to you.

http://www.displayobject.fr/2010/03/07/create-cmd-aliases-in-windows/

Hope this helps

Comment: ah, haven't used doskey in 20 years and forgot about it. thanks!

Comment: Be careful with doskey macros. They only work from the command line. They do not work within batch scripts.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard, but some commands can get default options from an environment variable.

COPY, XCOPY, and MOVE all can get a default `/Y` option from the COPYCMD variable. The default value can be overridden with the `/-Y` option on the command line.

DIR can get any option from the DIRCMD variable. Default environment variable values can be overridden by prefixing the option with `-` on the command line, for example `/-W`

There may be other variables to control some other commands, but I am not aware of them.

Unlike DOSKEY macros, the defaults specified by environment variables apply to both batch scripts and the command line.

Comment: great answer!  I wish I could split yours and Matthew's as both accepted.

Comment: Just noticed that command help also provides this info.  `dir /?` prints following at the bottom: `Switches may be preset in the DIRCMD environment variable.  Override preset switches by prefixing any switch with - (hyphen)--for example, /-W.`